# Unable to concatenate defined string and the text within the path to image file

Tags: delphi, resources

I got a problem with setting a path to image within the resource file (.rc).

For some reasone it was not possible to concatenate defined string and the text.

e.g.

```
File1:  
#define Path "Brand_1"

File2:  
#include File1

Logo BITMAP Path "\Logo.bmp"
```

Borland resource compiler (5.4) throws error message: 39: Cannot open file: Brand_1

EDIT: 
My question would be: Is is possible to combine the path for loading image using resource string variable and a string (file name).

Also, project I'm working on relates to a file (Logo.bmp) being present in two locations. I would like to have a switch (.bat file) to generate a different resouce file depending on requirements.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for stating those facts. What is your question? If you'd like to file a bug report, please visit [Embarcadero Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com).

Comment: So far as I can tell, neither brcc32 not rc support any form of string literal concatenation

Comment: My question is: Is it possible to combine a path for loading image from it's name and a resource string variable holding a path.

Answer (score 2):

BRCC32 accepts -i as search path seperated by semicolon, so you could create a bat file like this

compile_res.bat

```
brcc32 -ic:\mypath1;c:\mypath2 resource_script
```

and you define your resource_script as normal, for ex:

resource_script.rc

```
myImg BITMAP Logo.bmp
myDOC RCDATA mydoc.doc
```

when you run the compile_res.bat, it will run the brcc32.exe with the search path, and having the bat file saves you from retyping the search path every time.

Comment: +1, that's right but what if the `Logo.bmp` will be, in the worst case, in all included paths and each `Logo.bmp` will be a different image ?

Comment: Yeah, that's the limitation of this aproach, i.e. each filename must be unique. BTW, having multiple logo.bmp files refering to different images just add confusion. I rather have unique name for each.

Comment: @Hendra That's pretty much what the problem is. Logo.bpm is in two different location and I would like to have a .bat switch.

Answer (score 1):

You're not *concatenating* anything. You're compiling to `Logo BITMAP "Brand_1" "\Logo.bmp"`, and `"Brand_1"` isn't a valid path to a bitmap file.

`#define` in the resource compiler acts sort of like find/replace in a text processor - not exactly, but close enough in this case.

You **might** get by (untested) with removing the quotes and space between them, as long as there are no space characters  in either the path or filename; otherwise, you're probably out of luck. (Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, anyway.)

Comment: In C and C++, adjacent string-literal tokens are automatically combined at compile time. I'm sure that was the intention here, too. I don't know whether Microsoft's resource compiler supports that.

Comment: You can even make a helper concatenation function like `#define Concat(a,b) a##b` and use it like `Logo BITMAP Concat(Brand_1, \Logo.bmp)` but it's for nothing since you cannot pass there quoted strings (it would produce `Brand_1""\Logo.bmp` what would limit you for spaces) or what is worse, defined constants.

Comment: @Rob: I'm not sure the resource compiler preprocessor is that refined.

Comment: @TLama I've been experimenting with your suggestion and so far made a little bit of progress. I've expanded your function to take three parameters: #define Concat(a,b,c) a##b##c <code><br/>; LOGO BITMAP Concat (Temp,/,splash.bmp) The Temp is a string. If I'll put string into a variable e.g.#define VariableTemp Temp LOGO BITMAP; Concat (VariableTemp,/,splash.bmp) Then compiler throws an error: Cannot open file: Temp Any suggestions?

Comment: @Rob, that's what I've mentioned like *what is worse, defined constants*. If you pass a define constant in such `Concat` function as the first parameter, you'll get the result same as in your question.