# c pre processor string concatenate

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

How do I combine pre-defined C values to generate a string.

```
#define APP_NUMBER 22
#define ICON_FILE  "../icons/"##APP_NUMBER##".ico"
```

so that in my .rc file I can do the following

```
 1000 ICON  ICON_FILE
```

instead of
     1000 ICON  "../icons/22.ico"

> > it didnt work

```
  #define MY_ICON_FILE 25
  #define STR(x) #x
  #define ICON_FILE_NUM(x) "../icons/" STR(x) ".ico"
  1000 ICON  ICON_FILE_NUM(MY_ICON_FILE)
```

compiler error

```
  can't open icon file `../icons/': Permission denied

  nothing was appended to "../icons/"
```

the closest I just got was by doing this:

```
  #define MY_ICON_FILE 25
  #define STR(x) #x
  #define ICON_FILE_NUM(x) "../icons/"STR(x)".ico" /// took out spaces
  1000 ICON  ICON_FILE_NUM(MY_ICON_FILE)
```

( taking out the spaces around STR(x) )

and got this compiler error

```
 can't open icon file `../icons/"25".ico': Invalid argument
```

Comment: Is this really a question about resource files, and not C?

Comment: I don't think this is a question about C.  Maybe if you retagged the question you would get a better answer.

Comment: What exactly is a `.rc` file? I guess it's some kind of resource file, but what kind? What environment are you using?

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
#define APP_NUMBER 22
#define STR(x) #x
#define ICON_FILE_NAME(num)  "../icons/" STR(num) ".ico"
#define ICON_FILE ICON_FILE_NAME(APP_NUMBER)

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("ICON_FILE = \"%s\"\n", ICON_FILE);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
ICON_FILE = "../icons/22.ico"
```

But the `ICON_FILE` macro expands to `"../icons/" "22" ".ico"`, which is valid syntax for C (adjacent string literals are concatenated), but probably not for a `.rc` file, which explains the "can't open icon file" message you're getting.

It looks like you're trying to use token-pasting to generate a string literal. The problem with that is that a *partial* string literal, containing an unmatched `"` character, cannot be a valid preprocessing token.  For example, you can't pass a single `"` as an argument to a macro.

Consider writing a program (script, whatever) that generates the appropriate `#define` directives for you.

Comment: It looks like this (string literals not concatenated by the resource compiler) is indeed the case, unfortunately: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11161985/163956

Comment: ok but how does it work in a RC file ( resource ) 
at the moment i have  1000 ICON  "../icons/59.ico" 
resource number 1000 is this icon, but i want to do 
1000 ICON ICON_FILE

Comment: @AshodApakian: "Resource files" are not a feature of the C language. If you want help with them, you'll need to tell us what environment you're using. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Windows resource files don't understand the C style literal string concatenation for most elements - string table may be the only exception.

The trick when working with pre-processor macros is then to not use strings as input starting point, the pre-processor doesn't know how to remove quotes.

It would also be helpful to concatenate only once - consider addition of search paths `"-I../icons/"` rather than adding paths to the resource names.

Pulled the following from boost, example using windows msvc which is using an additional level of indirection than what I have seen in most places.

```
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT(a, b) BOOST_PP_CAT_OO((a, b))
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_OO(par) BOOST_PP_CAT_I ## par
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I(a, b) a ## b

#    define BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(text) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE_A((text))
#    define BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE_A(arg) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE_I arg
#    define BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE_I(text) #text
```

In examples seems you could just perform 
`BOOST_PP_CAT(../icons/, BOOST_PP_CAT(num,.ico))`

There is an issue passing to stringize only the outer CAT is applied (On windows at least).  So 
`BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_CAT(../icons/, BOOST_PP_CAT(num,.ico)))` doesn't work.

Addition for concatenation of 3 items

```
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT2(a, b, c) BOOST_PP_CAT_OO2((a, b, c))
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_OO2(par) BOOST_PP_CAT_I2 ## par
#    define BOOST_PP_CAT_I2(a, b, c) a ## b ## c
```

In my testing VS2013 an input of

- `..` is being converted to `"..."` which makes working with relative path `difficult`
- `\` needs to be escaped `\\` to work in macro args,  but is being converted to `"\\"` - using `/` for path works better

Working against the string table can be easier to see output than working with icons

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
  123  BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_CAT(APP_NUMBER, .ico))
  124  BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_CAT2(../icons/, APP_NUMBER,.ico)))
END
```

I haven't yet worked out resolution of .. being converted to ...
I had the following work using the additional search path,

```
1000        ICON        BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_CAT(APP_NUMBER, .ico))
1001        ICON        BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_CAT2(icons/, APP_NUMBER, .ico))
```

Answer (score -1):

I would honestly avoid doing this using preprocessor. Debugging preprocessor errors is a pain and I've seen cases where multiple layers of preprocessor replacements and concatenations were used, resulting in disaster when trying to find issues. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you will be able to do it with C pre-processor.  However, you could do it with m4 pre-processor.

```
linux_prompt> cat icon.m4
define(APP_NUMBER, 22)

1000 ICON "../icons/APP_NUMBER.ico"

linux_prompt> m4 icon.m4

1000 ICON "../icons/22.icon"
```

You have to make sure that the rest of the file expands correctly.  Do 'man m4' for more info.